# Writing a Lua wrapper, how to return a value from the stack using a method that could return multiple types?

Tags: c++, lua

Could someone explain to me why the following code doesn't work and offer a suggestion as to what I could do to make it work. I am open to using Boost, but I would prefer not to if possible. It should be fairly obvious what I'm trying to do from the code. **The problem is that I don't know what type the method will be returning until run time?**

```
template <typename T>
T getAs()
{
  if(typeid(T) == typeid(std::string))
return lua_tostring(lua, stackPos);

  if((typeid(T) == typeid(int)) || (typeid(T) == typeid(long)))
return lua_tointeger(lua, stackPos);

  if((typeid(T) == typeid(float)) || (typeid(T) == typeid(double)))
return lua_tonumber(lua, stackPos);

  if(typeid(T) == typeid(bool))
return lua_toboolean(lua, stackPos);
}
```

Part of the error message:

```
In file included from ./luaStackResult.hpp:32:
./luaStackItem.hpp:53:9: error: no viable conversion from 'lua_Integer' (aka 'long') to 'std::basic_string<char>'
    return lua_tointeger(lua, stackPos);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/lua.h:320:28: note: expanded from macro 'lua_tointeger'
#define lua_tointeger(L,i)    lua_tointegerx(L,i,NULL)
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:20:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'cppLua::luaStackItem::getAs<std::basic_string<char> >' requested here
cout << I.getAs<std::string>() << endl;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates are a compile time concept, not a runtime concept. There is no template code in a binary. Therefore your getAs cannot compile as it is: you can't return one type sometimes, and another type some other times. However, you could do something like

```
// define general template:
template <typename T> T getAs();

// define specializations for different returned types: 
template <> std::string getAs<std::string>() { return lua_tostring(lua, stackPos); }
template <> int         getAs<int>()         { return lua_tointeger(lua, stackPos); }
template <> float       getAs<float>()       { return lua_tonumber(lua, stackPos); }
template <> bool        getAs<bool>()        { return lua_toboolean(lua, stackPos); }
```

Then when you do

```
cout << getAs<std::string>() << endl;
```

the compiler will pick the correct specialization. The runtime will only contain the template instantiations of `getAs` that have been used in your source code.